# Keyboard shortcut to Insert a new row in Excel on a Mac with a Swedish keyboard

Tags: microsoft-excel, macos, keyboard-shortcuts

I’ve tried pretty much everything I can think of at this point, but maybe someone will have the answer: is it possible to insert a new row with a keyboard shortcut on a Mac with a Swedish keyboard?

The default Mac answer is to use `cmd` + `shift` + `+`. But on a Swedish keyboard, `+` is the default action on the key, and holding `shift` turns it into a `?`, causing Excel to open the help panel instead.

Comment: Do you have the app/OS running in English or Swedish? Key commands are listed in the Help, but idk if they're properly reconfigured if your language is set to other than English.

Comment: The Help section for keyboard shortcuts says “The shortcuts in this topic refer to the US keyboard layout. Keys for other layouts might not correspond exactly to the keys on a US keyboard.” and “The settings in some versions of the Mac operating system (OS) and some utility applications might conflict with keyboard shortcuts and function key operations in Microsoft 365 for Mac.” Neither of which is particularly helpful.

Comment: Ah, OK. Less than useful. I couldn't check for myself, I'm in English right the way through.

Comment: When I borrow my gf mac is like : Shift + Spacebar, then Command + Plus (+) 

Have you looked at your keyboard shortcut if you have changed anything?

Comment: Nope, that does nothing; it’s probably because that you’re pressing `cmd` + `shift` + `+`? Haven’t changed any shortcuts, either in Excel or macOS, that I’m aware of.

Answer (score 3):

A colleague pointed me at `cmd` + `shift` + `=`, which I can confirm is a shortcut for inserting a new row in Excel on macOS with a Swedish keyboard.

Comment: Which is actually identical to that in English, as + is actually shifted = on an English keyboard. If they'd put that in the manual properly, you'd have found it a whole lot earlier. [I was going to mention it in my first comment, but went off in the wrong direction instead, sorry :\

Comment: Tbh I should have clocked that too.

Comment: I'm on Swedish keyboard and trying to find ANY way to just insert at least one row below the row I am on. Non of all internets shortcuts tips are working. At least this is the first shortcut that works to add at least above. But what is the way to add rows below on a Swedish keyboard??